# Aprovar ou recusar uma requisição através do HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, segurança, spring-mvc

Sabe-se que todas as requisições por `@RequestMapping` são "públicas", onde qualquer usuário pode acessá-las através do navegador.

**A questão é, como aprovar Requests onde apenas o sistema pode requisitar e recusar tal request caso sejá acessado pelo usuário diretamente no navegador.**

Atualmente estou validando uma **key** vinda do **Request Header**, porém existem plugins que podem alterar o header, "cagando" com toda a lógica.

Para melhor entendimento, estou usando o seguinte codigo para verificar a **key**, onde caso o request tenha a **key** que estou comparando, ele deixa o request ser executado, se não ele bloqueia.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object controller) throws Exception {

    String Accept = request.getHeader("Authority");

    if(Accept != null && Accept.equalsIgnoreCase("KeyDefinida")){
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Chamada ajax

```
$.ajax
({
   url: "",
   headers: {          
     "Authority" : "KeyDefinida"
   },
```

Comment: Oi Matheus, se você realmente precisa de autenticação / autorização eu daria uma olhada no [Spring Security](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), criando um usuário único para o sistema. Porém esse tipo de problema volta e meia pode ser resolvido em outra camada. E.g., serviços do sistema podem ficar escondidos do usuário final (topologia do sistema).

Comment: @Matheus Já pensou na possibilidade de usar token?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Tipo oq eu passo pelo header?

Comment: @Matheus Sim, porém vc usaria uma biblioteca pra fazer isso.No meu caso eu uso JWT, Mas como citado acima vc pode usar Spring Security

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Vou dar uma olhada nessa biblioteca. Vlw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia, a solução mais viável, confiável e adequada no seu caso acredito que seria trabalhar com o `spring-security`:

**pom**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Para habilitar o spring-secutiry você vai precisar da anotação `@EnableWebSecurity`
Você vai precisar configurar os usuários para dentro do contexto spring, você pode configurá-los `inMemory` se for utilizar apenas a restrição a alguns entry points para o sistema, ou usuários fixos:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        //Caso o usuario de sistema pode ser tbm adm, mais se preferir pode deixar apenas System
        .withUser("UsuarioSistema").password("SenhaUsuarioSistema").roles("SYSTEM", "ADMIN").and()
        //Não é obrigatório
        .withUser("usuario1").password("senha1").roles("USER");
}
```

Ou trabalhar com uma implementação de `UserDetailsService`

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

Para trabalhar com o `UserDetailsService` segue um exemplo com `jpa` (mas você pode trabalhar com qualquer base de dados):

**Sua tabela de usuários**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    //Gets e Sets
}
```

**Sua tabela de Permissões**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    //Gets e Sets
}
```

**Interface de repositório para o usuario**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Interface de repositório para as permissões**

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
}
```

**Implementação da UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Finalmente o ultimo passo, você vai precisar configurar os padrões de segurança que irá utilizar, basicamente ele lhe permite fazer várias configurações, vou deixar um exemplo de configuração utilizando x509 (chave privada e publica), proteção contra ataque xss e desabilitando o token de ações do csrf (validação de ações permitidas ao usuário). O spring-security existe um universo de configurações que você pode utilizar ou personalizar, sugestão de links [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), [algaworks](http://blog.algaworks.com/spring-security/) e [devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-spring-security/29402)

**Configuração geral do spring-security**

```
//Classe de configuração geral do spring-security
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Padrões de configuração de seu sistema
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //Autorização para requisições
        http.authorizeRequests()
            //Permite acesso de todos para / para frente
            .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll().and()
            //Permite acesso apenas de usuarios System para /meuEndPoint/ para frente
            .antMatcher("/meuEndPoint/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("SYSTEM")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();

        //Configurações
        http.x509().and()
            .headers().xssProtection().and().and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Ainda dentro das configurações `SecurityConfiguration`, se você utilizou o `UserDetailsService` vai precisar injetar a implementação de `UserDetailsService` e implementar o método `configureGlobal` desta forma:

**Configuração UserDetailsService**

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

caso tenha utilizado o usuario inMemory vc vai precisar implementar o `configureGlobal` desta forma:

**Configuração inMemory**

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("UsuarioSistema").password("SenhaUsuarioSistema").roles("SYSTEM", "ADMIN").and()
            .withUser("usuario1").password("senha1").roles("USER");
    }
```

Outro ponto importante, se você deseja utilizar algum tipo de criptografia (altamente recomendado), precisa injetar o `BCryptPasswordEncoder`:

**Criptografia**

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

além disto mudar o configureGlobal para

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

lembrando que com a criptografia habilitada você deve salvar no banco ou inMemory a senha de usuários já encriptada.

Comment: Excelente responta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o header ***"User-Agent"***.

Este header oferece informações de onde o usuário vem.

Segue um exemplo de User-Agent:

**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36

Você pode testar com os navegadores que deseja dar suporte e apenas aceitar estes headers.

Espero ter ajudado,

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object controller) throws Exception {

    String accept = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); //Deixei o nome da variável em CamelCase por padrão.

    if(accept != null && accept.contains("Mozilla")) {
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Acho que ele não está importando com o navegador que faz a requisição, mas o usuário em si...